# Excel - How to return item details (entire row of data including a sku) using a sku on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have found many questions around this but I can't quite land it to my specific need. I am not looking for someone to do this work for me, more I am looking for guidance on how best to ask the question so I can dig it out and learn.

My issue...

We print tshirts and have 192,000 individual sku numbers (over 2600 designs with style, color and size variations on each). The products are maintained on Shopify. I have an export of the items that is broken into 3 workbooks, with a max of 72,000 skus per workbook.

My current project is to work with a team to inventory our clearance products (shirts that were misprinted or returned) and add them to shopify as new products at a discount. To start the project one of the team members went through 145 shirts using a master list I gave her of the shirt descriptions. She then added the style (hoodie, tshirt etc), color and size to the designs that she found. I then used a macro to pull the lines she had updated into a new sheet and used vlookup formula to complete the sku.

I now have a list of SKU's that need to be added to the site.

My thought was to use the SKU on that sheet (clearance) to pull over the entire row of data from the 3 SKU workbooks (Inventory1, 2 and 3). I would then look for duplicates and load those lines up to Shopify.

I have spent the morning looking for examples of using vlookup to pull back an entire row of data into 'Clearance'. Not finding a clear answer, I am wondering now if it makes more sense to work on the 'Inventory' sheets and count the SKU's on the 'Clearance' sheet instead.

Will ultimately only upload the exact SKUs (and all associated data) to Shopify to make a new product with a qty.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to loop through the columns of Sku's and then loop through the workbooks with master data.

You can probably write SQL against the source data workbook and prolly get super duper results but will require youre own tinkering :)

here is something to get you started

```
 strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
               & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
               & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

 strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

Comment: Doug, thanks for the quick response! Would there be any way to approach this just using Excel? It is all I have available to me currently. If not I would certainly enjoy learning SQL as it would likely make this incredibly simple (relatively)

Comment: Well this would be in excel (visual studio). You could go the loop route though, but that might take a minute depending on your computer, version of excel and how you move data around.